# Using an icon for links opening an lightbox

Tags: usability, lightbox

On one of our sites we decided to use lighboxes in 2 instances. I am aware of pros and cons of using lightboxes so this is not a topic for a discussion.
But I'd like to get your opinion about using small icons denouncing that clicking link will open a lightbox. Something like below. What do you think?
[alt text http://design.vitalbmx.com/images/misc/lightbox_icon.gif](http://design.vitalbmx.com/images/misc/lightbox_icon.gif)

Comment: Light rectangle on darker background is for a new content window on a dark overlay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a good idea, similar to the icons used on some sites to denotes another browser window will be opened.

If you include the 'X' in the top cornor, just make sure the icons doesn't look like a checkbox. Also maybe grey it out slightly so it looks like a silhouette...less intrusive in the interaction.

Good one

Answer (score 1):

A mini-lightbox icon is probably your best bet. It’ll look more like a light box if you include the lightbox’s X-to-close control in the icon. It’s okay if the X is disproportionally large in order to be visible (icons are cartoons, afterall), as long as it’s clearly in an upper corner. If you show the icon to three people and ask them what it is, be satisfied if two out of three say it’s a light box, dialog box, or window.

If you’re using thumbnails rather than text links, you could use the magnifying-glass-with-plus-sign-icon to suggest users can zoom in the see the full image or object. That’s especially helpful if you use animation to have the lightbox swell out of the thumbnail.